# How can I filter according to index with Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple tab system but I'm a bit stuck on exactly how to make this work.

I'm using ng-repeat to spit out the tabs and the content and so far this is working fine.

Here are my tabs:

```
<ul class="job-title-list">
     <li ng-repeat="tab in tabBlocks">
        <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="activeTab($index)">dummy content</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

And here's the repeated content which needs to match up to the tabs:

```
<div ng-repeat="content in contentBlocks">
    <p>more dummy content</p>
</div>
```

And finally, my function (the console log returns the correct indexes from the tabs)

```
$scope.activeTab = function(i) {

   $scope.selectedTab = i
   console.log($scope.selectedTab)

}
```

Any suggestions on how I should go about this? I've looked into ng-show, ng-switch and ng-if to show and hide the appropriate content but I've been stuck on this for a while...

Many thanks!

Comment: What is your tabBlocks and contentBlocks array contains please post your data too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tabset concept using bootstrap js.

```
<tabset>
<tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled" id="{{tab.href}}">
 <div ng-include="tab.href"></div>
</tab>
</tabset>
```

and below use ng-template to put your code.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tab.href">
<div>
 Testing Div
</div>
```

Your tab id and ng-include will be the same like script ng-template id.

You can make number of ng-template as number of your tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently looked into a way of making the bootstrap tab work with angular without the need for bootstrap.js and the like. I'm pretty happy with what I ended up with.

This is the html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-ng-controller="NavigationCtrl">
    <li data-ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
        data-ng-class="{'active': activeTab === tab }">
        <a ng-click="go(tab)" href="">{{ tab.title }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" data-ng-controller="NavigationCtrl">
    <div data-ng-repeat="tab in tabs" class="tab-pane"
         data-ng-class="{'active': activeTab === tab }" id="content">
         <div data-ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It uses a navigation controller, which is this:

```
app.controller("NavigationCtrl", ["$scope", "$location", function ($scope, $location) {

    // all the tabs and their ng-view locations
    $scope.tabs = [
        { id: 'content', title: 'random content', route: '/content' },
        { id: 'dialog', title: 'dialog', route: '/dialog' },
        { id: 'form', title: 'some form', route: '/form' },
        { id: 'grid', title: 'some grids', route: '/grid' }
    ];

    // Initially start with the first tab 
    $scope.activeTab = $scope.tabs[0];

    // this gets the tab object from a location/route
    var tabByRoute = function (route) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tabs.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.tabs[i].route === route) {
                return $scope.tabs[i];
            }
        }

        return $scope.tabs[0];
    };

    $scope.go = function (tab) {
        $location.path(tab.route);
    };

    // If the path is changed in some other part of the application, this event fires.
    $scope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function () {
        $scope.activeTab = tabByRoute($location.path());
    });
}]);
```

I hope you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the index of the tab clicked and show/modify content based on the index.

http://plnkr.co/edit/nkdUJD6GMZHGEpXpDRoN?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-  beta.5/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
<style>
  .active{border-color:red;}
</style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="test">
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<div ng-repeat="tab in data">
  <button ng-class="{active:uiModel.activeIndex==$index}" 
          ng-click="uiModel.activeIndex=$index">{{tab}}</button>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="tab in data" 
     ng-show="uiModel.activeIndex==$index">{{$index}}</div>
<script>
  var app=angular.module("app",[]);
  app.controller("test",function($scope){
    $scope.data=["tab1","tab2","tab3"];
    $scope.uiModel={activeIndex : 0}
  });
  angular.bootstrap(document,[app.name]);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your content repeat div to this and you should be fine (it works for me at least):

```
<div ng-show="$index==selectedTab" ng-repeat="content in contentBlocks">
<p>more dummy content</p>
</div>
```